# How do I write an external connection string config file and make my c# application recognize and read it?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

My current c# windows form application is using the following code to connect to a database to retrieve information and the it is stored at Setting.cs

```
public static String connectionString ="Data Source=####; Initial Catalog=###; User ID=####; Password='####'";
```

I have written out an external Connection.config file and the content would be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" providerName="System.Data.providername" 
         connectionString="Data Source=####; Initial Catalog=###; User ID=###;                      Password='####!';" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

is the above code written correctly? as I sort of just copied and paste online and editted the connection string part as i do not know what does the "add name" and providerName part does.

what i would like to ask is where should i write the code in my forms to read the connection string from my external config file so i can remove the one in my setting.cs file.

thank you.

don mind the ### as it is just replaced by me to represent the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your web.config file right at the bottom above the closing config tag.

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add connectionString="Data Source=Servernamegoeshere;Initial Catalog=databasenamehere;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***" name="nameyouwanttogivethisconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

To reference the connection on the page load of the main form use this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameyouwanttogivethisconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("update table etc etc....",SqlConnection);
        SqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //This line is for updates and inserts, use SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); for select statments
        SqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Make sure you add these references to the top of the page you are using this code on:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

You may then use that connection to create a Sqlcommand to run against your database.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. it was a very complete answer. however there is a small issue. it says the name configurationmanager does not exist in the current context. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You may need to add a reference, let me snag that for you.

Comment: I believe that as long as you have: using System.Configuration; and using System.Data.SqlClient; at the top of the page when you paste in the code for page load it should pick up the references. http://i.imgur.com/UF8DF.png

Comment: Apparently there's an order to which you must paste to have VS pick up on the references. Under solution explorer, right click on the references folder and click add reference. Add system.configuration. Paste in the using block from the above code, and then paste in the code itself. Everything should work fine.

Comment: No problem, if it worked out for you, it helps people here to up-vote the solution and accept it by clicking on the button next to my answer so people can see what worked for you if they have the same question in the future. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use config source to split your config files. Example App/web.config:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="myExternalConfigSource.xml" />
```

External Config:

```
<connectionStrings>          
  <add name="Connection" providerName="System.Data.providername" 
     connectionString="Data Source=####; Initial Catalog=###; User ID=###; />
</connectionStrings>
```

More info: http://www.nikhilk.net/Entry.aspx?id=158

If you use this method, you can reference your config as normal and still have your configuration split out into seperate files.

Answer (score 1):

we use:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="connection.string" value="Initial Catalog=XXX;server=localhost;User=YYY;Password=ZZZ;" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and then just:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection.string"];
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. but where do i put the second part at? i have a loginform and mainform and i am suppose to retrieve the information at mainForm.

Comment: when you create a DB connection: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection.string"];

Comment: and one more detail, System.Configuration must be referenced and added to using

Comment: hi. there is an error with ConfigurationManager. it says that the name  does not exist in current context. any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ApplicationSettings, and forget about writing information in config files manually (It will be done automatically)

1. Right click on your project in solution explorer and select Properties.
2. Go to Settings tab.
3. Click on the link to create the settings file. (It will be called Settings.settings)
4. For Name, type the name you want to use for the connection string. (i.e. ConnectionString)
5. For Type, select Connection String
6. For Scope, select Application
7. For Value paste your connection string.

When you want to use it, just type

```
Application.Settings.Default.ConnectionString
```

i.e

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Application.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
```